# Getting select query by edittext SELECT

Tags: java, php, android, json, mysqli

Hi i want to get data from the server when someone enters an id in the edittext, if it is there the data that matches should show up in the textviews.

I got it working with a static id, so lets say i got number 1 in the `SELECT * FROM TABLE where id='1'` And if Number `1` was entered in the edittext, number 1's data will show up.

`null` is normally shown in my browser.

But now that i use `$id=_REQUEST['id']` the jsonparser only returns NPE(NullPointerException), because the jsonparser shows an error: `Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value nulln of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` i Suppose the query isnt fired.

Im gonna show you my JSON Parser class, and a piece of my php.

```
 <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
 exit();
}
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$result = $mysqli->query("Select * From Table where id = '$id'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
 $rows=$row;
} 
echo json_encode($rows);
$result->close();
$mysqli->close();?>
```

Json Parser class

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
String id;
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {
}
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", ""));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have SQL injection hole in your code. You can't use any variable in your sql query without validation! Try use PDO http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php.

Secondly, it seems that you have no trasnfer correct value of ID from Java to PHP and you are searching rows with ID = ''.

Thirdly, $rows = $row will not work. Add $rows = array(); before while and then use $rows[] = $row;.

Comment: I dont understand the second part, what do you mean by incorrect transfer value? Since the contents of the id to be searched, are dependent of the edittext value, i thought i should leave it empty.

Comment: You have params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "")); so, in my opinion, ID value transfered to PHP is empty. Did you test this part of application?

Comment: i changed to edittext String, edit=edt.getText().toString();

But how do you mean te transfer, because im not quite sure how to pass the variable $id in java